# React function loose state on second try

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

this code works properly on first and third try, there's always a step where it bugs and send no data to the db, it ruin my business logic every time, I tried with and without page reload got the same results

```
  apiCall = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
    let userEmail = currentUser.email;
    let userUnderscore = userEmail.replace(/\./g, '_');
    let intervalMS = this.state.interval * 60000;
    let url = `https://url.com/api/v1/${userUnderscore}/${this.state.urlTask}?url=${this.state.urlTask}&width=${this.state.width}&interval=${intervalMS}&user=${userUnderscore}&running=true`;
    if (this.state.interval >= 1 && this.state.urlTask !== "") {
      fetch(url)
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ addURLError: true, loading: false });
    }
    this.setState({ addURL: true, addURLError: false });
    fire.database().ref(`/master/users/${userUnderscore}/setup/`)
      .update({
        running: true,
        interval: this.state.interval,
        url: this.state.urlTask,
      });
    setTimeout(
      function () {
        this.setState({ addURL: false, running: true });
        window.location.reload();
      }.bind(this), 2000
    );
  }

  ...

  <Button color='black' onClick={this.apiCall} animated='vertical' type='submit'>
```

**EDIT**

The function and the db actually get updated, the issue is that on second try the state is empty even if the form hold values

Comment: setState is async... Is your code prepared for async and sync mixed functions?

Comment: @joaozito-polo I don't think so

Comment: for example... look your if/else with a setState, and after, a second setState... they don't will run in this moment, and after return from your entire function, both will run before a new render

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by reloading the app before any attempt of executing the function, that way there's always a fresh state to be used : `window.location.reload();`